Is $f(L\cap \Omega)$ contained in an analytic curve?
We say that $\Gamma\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ is an analytic curve if there exists a real analytic function $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $\Gamma\subseteq g([0,1])$ and that $g'(t)\neq0$ for all $t\in [0,1]$.
Now let  $f$ be a complex analytic function on a connected open set $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}$, and let $L$ be a straightline on $\mathbb{C}$. It is possible that $L\cap\Omega$ is divided into several many line segments. I wonder if $f(G\cap\Gamma)$ is contained in an analytic curve? I hope that it is true but I am not sure. Thank you for your helping!

Note that a real analytic curve that contains a segment is a segment (by the identity theorem and noting that real analytic $g$ on a closed interval extends to complex analytic on a small rectangle) and then take your domain st the real axis cuts into two segments say and find $f$ real on one and non real on another (an incomplete annulus around the origin and a square root will do)

Thank you for your help but I am sorry that I still do not know exactly   how to stsrt. What puzzled me is that: Since $G\cap L$ may consists of several line segments, then $f(G\cap L)$ consists of several analytic curves. But I do not know if these curves are contained in the same analytic curve. @Conrad

posted an answer with more details

The OP question has a negative answer and a counterexample is obtained by taking $G$ an incomplete annulus around the origin (say $1 < |z|<2, |\arg z -3\pi/2| >1/100$).
Then with $L$ the real line, the intersection with the domain is formed by the segments $-2<x<-1, 1<x<2$ and if $f(z)=\sqrt z$ obtained by analytic continuation from the usual positive square root on $1<x<2$, then $f(1<x<2)$ is a positive real segment, while $f(-2<x<-1)$ is a segment on the imaginary axis.
Now if $\Gamma$ is an analytic curve that contains a segment, then $\Gamma$ must be also a segment - this easily follows by analytic continuation as by a rotation we can assume the segment is on the real axis so extending the defining real analytic function of the curve, $g:[0,1]$ to a complex analytic function on a small (conjugate invariant) neighborhood of $[0,1]$ in the plane we have $g(z)=\overline {g(\bar z)}$ on the piece of $[0,1]$ sent into the real line segment by hypothesis, hence everywhere so $g[0,1]$ is real so a real segment.
In particular, the two segments above of $f(G\cap\Gamma)$ are perpendicular, hence cannot be part of the same analytic curve.

Thank you very much! I understand.
